# AspectJ iajc compiler fails on child annotations

Tags: java, ant, aspectj

I'm using ant 1.9.3 with aspectjtools 1.8.5. When I'm trying to compile project using iajc compiler failes with message

```
[aspectj:iajc] error at @NamedQueries({
[aspectj:iajc]  ^^^^^^^^^^^
[aspectj:iajc] /path/to/file/Speech.java:14:0::0 Speech.NamedQueries is not an annotation type
[aspectj:iajc] warning at /path/to/file/PermissionCheckerAspect.java:23::0 advice defined in package.PermissionCheckerAspect has not been applied [Xlint:adviceDidNotMatch]
[aspectj:iajc] MessageHolder:  (10732 info)  (2 warning)  (1 error) 
[aspectj:iajc] [error   0]: error at @NamedQueries({
[aspectj:iajc]  ^^^^^^^^^^^
[aspectj:iajc] /path/to/file/Speech.java:14:0::0 Speech.NamedQueries is not an annotation type
```

My ant target configuration looks like this code snippet

```
<target name="compile.aspectj" depends="copy-libs">
    <aspectj:iajc source="1.8" destDir="war/WEB-INF/classes">
        <sourceroots>
            <pathelement location="src"/>
        </sourceroots>
        <classpath refid="project.class.path"/>
    </aspectj:iajc>
</target>
```

I have to use compile time weaving. How can I deal with it?

Here is my aspect code

```
@Aspect
public class PermissionCheckerAspect {
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PermissionCheckerAspect.class);
    public PermissionCheckerAspect() {
        info("Instantiating PermissionChecker aspect");
    }

    @Around("execution(public * *(..)) && within(package.LicenseRequired)")
    public Object around(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) {
        try {
            info("Proceeding...");
            Object proceed = joinPoint.proceed();
            info("Proceeded successfully");
            return proceed;
        } catch (Throwable throwable) {
            throw new RuntimeException(throwable);
        }
    }

}
```